# How to see the voltage in Conky?

Tags: conky, sensors

I want to monitor the voltage in conky and do not know how to put it.I have Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
The sensor output is next:

```
dell_smm-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
Processor Fan: 2901 RPM
CPU:            +40.0°C  
Ambient:        +38.0°C

BAT0-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:          15.23 V  
curr1:         1.12 A  

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +41.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +42.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +39.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

pch_skylake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +38.5°C  

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +25.0°C  (crit = +107.0°C)
```

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At its simplest you can run a command, say every 60 seconds, to parse the output of `sensor` with `awk`:

```
${execi 60 sensors | awk '/^in0/{print $2}'} Volts
```

---

If you want to combine the two, it would be more optimal to run the sensors command just once and extract the data in one awk:

```
${execi 5 sensors | awk '/^curr1/{A=$2} /^in0/{V=$2} END{printf "%s A %s V",A,V}'}
```

I would recommend using `execi` and a number of seconds, else the command will be repeated every second by default.

---

For the pch temp1 value, because there are 2 lines beginning `temp1:`, you can make awk exit after it has printed the first one, and use a `%d` format to convert the float value to integer:

```
${execi 5 sensors | awk '/^temp1/{t=$2;printf "%d C",t;exit}'}
```

Comment: thanks for the guide. I put $ {exec sensors | awk '/^curr1/{print $2}'} mA
${exec sensors | awk '/^in0/{print $2}'} V

Comment: now that I'm looking at it... could it be that the monitoring of two more cores is missing in the coretemp-isa-0000 since it is an intel core i5 Skylake?

Comment: I don't know about the number of cores. I've updated my answer on how you can combine the two execs into one, for efficiency.

Comment: What does the temperature of "Package id 0" and "pch_skylake-virtual-0" mean?

Comment: You would need to look at the intel chipset architecture and the [lm-sensors](https://github.com/lm-sensors/lm-sensors/tree/master/configs/Intel) configuration for the chipset.

Comment: if i can see the PCH temperature... is correct the next command? ${GOTO 65}${execi 1 sensors|grep "temp1" | cut -d ':' -f2 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d '.' -f1} C

Comment: The problem is there are 2 lines beginning `temp1`. See my edited answer for an awk solution.